# How to change UIButton font iOS6

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

Hi i have problem with titleLabel property. When I want to change it. The changes don't apear.
This is my code:

```
UIButton *menuItemButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 290.0, 35.0)];
[menuItemButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[menuItemButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        menuItemButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[menuItemButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 11.0, 0, 0)];
[menuItemButton setTitle:(NSString *)[itemParams objectForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[menuItemButton setBackgroundImage:menuItemImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[menuItemButton setTag:idx];
[[menuItemButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Vardana" size:5]];
[menuItemButton addTarget:self action:@selector(menuItemClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And this is not working:

```
[[menuItemButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Vardana" size:15]];
```

I'm also try:

```
[menuItemButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Vardana" size:15]];
menuItemButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Vardana" size:15];
```

Other properties of titleLabel also not work for ex. alignment and color.

All thigs I'm write in `viewDidLoad` after `[super viewDidLoad];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct name for the font is `Verdana` instead of `Vardana`. You can check the names of several fonts in http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6000-list-of-uifonts-available.html

Comment: I write that any of textLabel property not work setting system font with size also.

Comment: Ok solved. I'm try to run in simulator and it's work. So i clean project and also work in Device.